# Make x options (choices) based on the number of folders

Tags: batch-file, cmd

As the title says I'm trying to make a batch that will:

```
for x NumberOfFolders, make x Choices/Options
```

I'm also running Windows XP. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just create an array of folder names and read the index of the desired one via a `set /P` command. Or create a string of digits/letters that will be used in a `choice` command. If there are more than 36 folders, also use lowcase letters. Or write a Batch-JScript hybrid script file to directly select the folder. Or...

Comment: [something like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+dynamic+menu)

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking; please take the [tour] and read [ask] for help clarifying this question. Take a look also on how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you something to get you started, *subject to it working on such an old, outdated and unsupported Operating System*.

```bat
@For /F %%A In ('Dir /W/AD-L') Do @Set /A #=%%A-2 2>Nul
@For /L %%A In (1,1,%#%) Do @Echo %%A. This is Option %%A
@Pause
```

---

**[Edit /]**

*…and because I've nothing else to do whilst waiting for my haircut!*

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('"Set # 2>Nul"') Do Set "%%A="
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%A In ('"Dir /B/AD-L|FindStr /N .*"'
) Do Set "#%%A=%%B" & Echo( %%A.    %%B
Echo( Choose a directory from the list&Echo(
:Opt
Set /P "Opt="
Set #|Findstr /B "#%Opt%=">Nul||GoTo :Opt
Call Echo( You Selected "%%#%Opt%%%"
Pause
```

Comment: It works! Although I would prefer if it showed the actual name of the folder instead of 'This is Option'. Also I'm not sure how the batch checks what option the user selected? I tried using `ERRORLEVEL` but it doesn't seem to work? To answer the OS confusion, yes I know Windows XP is outdated, my main OS is Ubuntu. The only reason I have Windows XP is because I play some really old games and my PC is quite old, that is also why I don't use Windows 10. I'm fairly new to batch and cmd and I don't always understand the online docs, so I apologize for my annoyance. EDIT:Thx,didnt refresh the page!

Comment: @WutwutBoody, if the code works for you, pleasse consider marking it as accepted, _by clicking on the large check mark to its left_. Also you don't need online docs, type the name of any command followed by **`/?`**, at the Command Prompt for its usage information, e.g. **`For /?`** or **`Set /?`**.